# playaudio2(sprintf("%s",mname),"wav");

Tags: octave

Octaveでwavファイルをplayaudio2で読み出そうとすると、エラーになります。

error: 'playaudio2' undefined near line 1 column 1

playaudio2という関数はなく、playaudioで変更するようですが、mフォルダには似たものとしてaudioplayerしかなさそうです。

Comment: 関連の有無は不明ですが、これ [playaudio() in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9288777/9014308) とか、これ [How do I play a sound in Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1478071/9014308) をたどると、何か情報があるかもしれません。特に後の記事には [playaudio is broken!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669212/9014308) という回答があります。あとどちらにも出てくる sox というのは、これ [SoX - Sound eXchange | HomePage](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) でしょうか。

Comment: playaudio2という関数の情報はどちらから得られたのでしょうか……？　`octave "playaudio2"` で検索しても何も得られず、`matlab "playaudio2"` で検索すると https://bitbucket.org/rholson1/wisp が出てきます。